# Any example for .NET proxy Web Service?

Tags: web-services, wcf, proxy

I want to create a .NET WebService (WCF) that the orders are coming from an external server from one port/endpoint  and do some processing on it before sending the orders through another port/endpoint to an internal server, and wait for the response from the internal server and further process the received response before sending a response back to the initiating external server.

```
External server/WS  <-> Proxy WS <-> Internal server/WS
```

what would be the best practice in creating the Proxy WS in this scenario? any sample code or example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example provided by Microsoft does the trick. It's web service acts as server and client which what proxy is. Of course it's a general solution and needs to be customized.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Unless someone else knows a better example, I would take this as a solution.